# test new object instance (jasmine)

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have tests run by karma, in one of them I create `new instance` of object and call `function` where is used `this`. On normal browser `this` is reference to current instance but in test after `console.log` it I see:

> Object{document:  < !-- This is the execution context.
>
> Loaded within the iframe. Reloaded before every execution run.

Why?

```js
// createing the object

window.gr = window.gr || {};

gr.Notification = (function () {
    function Notification(node, message) {
        this.liveTime = 5000;
        this.template = this.createTemplate(message);
        this.node = null;
        this.appendTo(node);

        setTimeout(this.remove, this.liveTime);
    }

    Notification.prototype = {
        createTemplate: function (message) {
            var notification = document.createElement("div");
            notification.className = "notification";

            var _message = document.createTextNode(message);
            notification.appendChild(_message);

            return notification;
        },
        appendTo: function(node){
            this.node = node.appendChild(this.template);
        },
        remove: function(){
            console.log(this)
            this.node.parentNode.removeChild(this.node);
        }
    };

    return Notification;
})();


//test

beforeEach(function(){
       Notification = gr.Notification;
        jasmine.clock().install();
    });

it("should remove notification after 5s", function(){
        new Notification(document.body);

        jasmine.clock().tick(5001);

        expect(document.querySelectorAll(NOTIFICATION_SELECTOR).length).toEqual(0);
    });
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could include the actual code, rather than a summary. The exact behavior may change depending on how and where you call the object.

Comment: It's hard to figurate what is happening, without the context, but, Jasmine Clean the body dom content after each "it", perheps you tried created this new instance inside a beforeEach?.

Comment: I edit post and add code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `this` references to `window`, because you call setTimeout, which is method of `window` object, so `this` inside that method points to `window`,

you could do something like that:

```
function Notification(node, message) {
        this.liveTime = 5000;
        this.template = this.createTemplate(message);
        this.node = null;
        this.appendTo(node);

        var self = this;

        setTimeout(function() {
            self.remove()
        }, self.liveTime);

    }
```